# .htaccess prevents code execution

Tags: php, .htaccess, security

what's wrong with this .htaccess file? it gives me an *500 Internet Server Error* when access the folder.

```
RemoveHandler .php .php3 .phps .pl .php4 .phtml .py .jsp .asp .htm .php .phtml .php3 .shtml .sh .cgi
RemoveType .php .php3 .phps .pl .php4 .phtml .py .jsp .asp .htm .php .phtml .php3 .shtml .sh .cgi
php_flag engine off
```

I'm trying to prevent execution of PHP file in a certain folder

Comment: Why not just have the host uninstall PHP? You're familiar with extension spoofing, right?

Comment: Have a look at Apache’s error_log log file.

Comment: check the edited version of the question

Comment: is PHP running as CGI mode or php_module? you can this check with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and search `Server API`  to get this information..

Comment: Raymond - It gives me this: Server API :CGI/FastCGI

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run this .htaccess file with no issues.

the RemoveHandler and RemoveType Directives require that the mod_mime module be loaded.  You can use phpinfo() to check for this.

just a heads up. when you disable PHP this way an end user will get the source code of any php script they attempt to access

something like this in your .htaccess will deny access to all files with a .php extension:

```
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

To exclude access to multiple file types (like .php OR .py OR etc...) use FilesMatch (allows regex).

the following will deny access to any files with a .php, .cgi, or .py extension:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php|cgi|py)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thank you, what about if I wanted to deny .php .cgi .py ?